Why is my STL array's first element it's size, but it's copy is what I defined for the original?
I wanted to learn about how to rotate a 1D array like a 2D array, but wound up finding this side-effect.
I had an STL array of 16 ints, and made a function to display the values in a 4x4 grid:
void func(std::array<int, 16> arr){
   for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){    
      std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
      if((i + 1) % 4 == 0) 
         std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}

but the first time I print an array (declared like this one specifically):
std::array<int, 16> arr{
   1, 2, 3, 4,
   0, 1, 2, 3, 
   0, 0, 1, 2,
   0, 0, 0, 1
};

The output is:
16 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 0 1 2
0 0 0 1

I know the first element is the size because I changed the parameter and OG arr size to 17, then printed the array's first element and the first element became 17, not the displayed value.
What's even stranger is that if I copied the array to another of the same size I would get the expected result (1 2 3 4, newline and everything else.) (I made a copy because I was going to try rotate it.)
I defined the copy like this:
for(int i = 0; i <= 16;++i){
   rotd_arr[i] = arr[i];
}

For the MRE requirers:
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void func(std::array<int, 16> arr){
   for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){    
      std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
      if((i + 1) % 4 == 0) 
         std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}

int main (){
  std::array<int, 16> arr{
     1, 2, 3, 4,
     0, 1, 2, 3, 
     0, 0, 1, 2,
     0, 0, 0, 1
  };
  std::array<int, 16> rotd_arr;
  for(int i = 0; i <= 16; ++i){
     rotd_arr[i] = arr[i];//yes, I know I could have used the overloaded operator "="
  }//yes, i also know there's an out-of-scope error
  
  func(arr);
  func(rotd_arr);
  //the two ins
  return 0;
}

UPDATE: minutes before posting this I found I had a scope error when I was copying the values from arr to rotd_arr. That fixed my problem, But now I have a different Question: Why was the first element the size of arr (or rotd_arr, I can't really test that quickly), and why wasn't it in rotd_arr instead of arr?

for(int i = 0; i <= 16;++i){ is a bug. It should be for(int i = 0; i < 16;++i){

Why i <= 16 in your for loop?  That should be i < 16.  So you access out-of-bounds -- so UB.

Please read about the [mcve].

A side note: func can get arr by const& to avoid a copy when calling it.

Post a [mcve]. .

"minutes before posting this I found [...]" -- If you found an error (not in the shown code) before posting, why did you still post?

In case someone needed the advice - to JaMiT,

Also, about the MRE failure, i didnt know, this is my first post on Syntax overflow.

The loop that copies from arr to rotd_arr causes your program, as a whole, to have undefined behaviour.   The consequences of undefined behaviour can be anything, including spurious output later on.   One of the "joys" of undefined behaviour is that symptoms can occur in any code in your program, not just in the code that actually causes the undefined behaviour.   Trying to reason about why particular erroneous output occurs is meaningless - the real goal needs to be to eliminate the problem, not explain it.

Also to WohlStad (sorry if I'm offensive or anything) but the issue is somewhere in:
for(int i = 0; i <= 16; ++i){
   rotd_arr[i] = arr[i];
}


You have this: for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i), then you have this: for(int i = 0; i <= 16;++i).  Why did you change the way you are accessing elements, with respect to the upper-bound?  The <= makes a lot of difference.

Still, if anyone else reading knows why the first element is the # of elements in either array, It would be very nice. This sounds very interesting to learn about.

if anyone else reading knows why the first element is the # of elements in either array -- As already mentioned, the behavior is undefined.

[Edit] your question with a [mcve].  That requires a main.

@NoahM "but the issue is somewhere in: for(int i = 0; i <= 16; ++i){ rotd_arr[i] = arr[i]; }" -- According to your question, the error occurs "the first time I print an array" with no mention of copying the array first. So it is perfectly legitimate to try to reproduce the error ignoring the last code block.

"I found I had a scope error" - from the UPDATE block yeah I noticed that too and cried internally. @PaulM

for(int i = 0; i <= 16;++i){ rotd_arr[i] = arr[i];} --> for(int i = 0; i <= 16;++i){rotd_arr.at(i) = arr.at(i); } -- Now your program will throw an std::out_of_range exception, instead of going ahead and giving you strange output.  Using [] to access elements in a std::array has no bounds-checking, while using at() does a bounds-check.

Most people here are focused on your indices. They are not wrong, but in C++ you should use range based for loops whenever you can : for(const auto value : arr). And to copy std::arrays, you can just use an assignment. Another idom : "avoid raw loops" e.g. rotd_arr = arr;

You should, as already noted, use range-based for loops, but if you're going to use a manual for loop, i should be declared as being of type std::size_t.

The likely reason that you get an output of 16 is that the bytes of i are copied when you do rotd_arr[16] = arr[16]

About your updated question about Undefined Behavior, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

General rule of thumb: If you see  <= in the exit condition of a loop iterating over a container, inspect the loop more closely and verify the range of the loop because you're probably looking at a bug.

"Why was the first element the size of arr (or rotd_arr, I can't really test that quickly), and why wasn't it in rotd_arr instead of arr?" -- This is no big mystery if you drop your pre-conceived notions. The problematic line is rotd_arr[i] = arr[i]; with both subscripts out of range. That means what you are assigning from could be anything; apparently on your system, arr[16] means "the size of arr" (or maybe i).  Also , what you are assigning to could be anything; apparently on your system rotd_arr[16] is an alias for arr[0] (as if the arrays were next to each other).

Compare the two loops you wrote:

for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){



for(int i = 0; i <= 16; ++i){


The second one accesses both arrays out-of-bounds, and undefined behavior is invoked. This means anything could happen, including the erroneous output you observe.
I'd recommend using std::copy to copy your array in this case.
std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), rotd_arr.begin());

Or just:
rotd_arr = arr;

Invoking copy-assignment.
